# I am having problems in android studio configuration can any help me?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I started Android Studio and installed it nd check in cmd also by Flutter doctor it shows everything right. But when I run hello world program it shows many errors can anyone help me plz. below i pasted the codes

error:

```
The method 'MaterialApp' isn't defined for the type 'MyApp'. (undefined_method at [helloword] lib\MyApp.dart:9)
error: The method 'ThemeData' isn't defined for the type 'MyApp'. (undefined_method at [helloword] lib\MyApp.dart:12)
error: Undefined name 'Colors'. (undefined_identifier at [helloword] lib\MyApp.dart:13)
error: Undefined name 'Colors'. (undefined_identifier at [helloword] lib\MyApp.dart:14)
error: The method 'Scaffold' isn't defined for the type 'MyApp'. (undefined_method at [helloword] lib\MyApp.dart:16)
error: The method 'AppBar' isn't defined for the type 'MyApp'. (undefined_method at [helloword] lib\MyApp.dart:17)
error: Undefined name 'Colors'. (undefined_identifier at [helloword] lib\MyApp.dart:19)
error: Named parameters must be enclosed in curly braces ('{' and '}'). (named_parameter_outside_group at [helloword] lib\main.dart:4)
error: A function body must be provided. (missing_function_body at [helloword] lib\main.dart:4)
error: Default values aren't allowed in function typed parameters. (default_value_in_function_typed_parameter at [helloword] lib\main.dart:4)
error: A function body must be provided. (missing_function_body at [helloword] lib\main.dart:4)
error: The function 'MyApp' isn't defined. (undefined_function at [helloword] test\widget_test.dart:16)
info: Name non-constant identifiers using lowerCamelCase. (non_constant_identifier_names at [helloword] lib\main.dart:4)
info: Unused import: 'package:helloword/main.dart'. (unused_import at [helloword] test\widget_test.dart:11)
```

Comment: Please put errors in your question.

Comment: 1.The method 'materialsapp' isn't defined for the type 'MyApp'. 2. The method 'themedata' isn't define for the type 'MyAp' 3.the function MyApp isn't defined. 4.the function MyApp isn't defined. Like this many errors are there

Comment: put you main page cods!

Comment: How? Actually today I just register here 

Comment: Don't know anything about it

Comment: Just need to edit your post and paste main code there!!Look other question and do like theme.

Comment: @Harshitrai follow steps given in [guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows) from flutter.dev

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed **Android studio flutter plugin** and Flutter sdk is set up in your **path**. 
Follow the [guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows) from flutter.dev

Comment: yes i have installed the flutter plugins as wel as dart plugins even in CMD it is not showing any issues .

Comment: run `flutter doctor --verbose` in cmd and post the output.

Comment: if everything is right then run `flutter pub get` in android studio.

Comment: below i have posted the output u can check

Answer (score 0):

May be you are missing the  material import.
make sure you have

`import: package: flutter/material.dart`

..also try running `flutter packages get` once again.

Hope it helps..

Comment: ya i checked.if u want to try and whats th probleams u can help me through anydesk

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\user>flutter doctor --verbose
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.836], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.17.3 at c:\src\flutter\flutter
    • Framework revision b041144f83 (6 days ago), 2020-06-04 09:26:11 -0700
    • Engine revision ee76268252
    • Dart version 2.8.4

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 46.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

Comment: run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

Comment: nope it won't help. alredy i have installed it its showing because i reintsalled the android studio

Comment: if u don't have any problem u can just help me from anydesk .